# Ajax call to action method not triggered on first click after session timeout

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC Application where I set session timeout. On timeout I am clearing cookie, ADFS signOut. When user clicks any link which will trigger ajax call to communicate to its respective controller.

The links are working if user has valid session, but same does not work once session timed out, On Immediate second click on that link its started working.

No error logged, But it did fire on javascript end but not to the controller.

please provide any suggestion